# Is it possible to search Box items based on the metadata?

Tags: box-api, boxapiv2

API documentation below does not mention how to search based on the metadata. Is it really possible? Can someone point me to an example?

https://developers.box.com/docs/#search

thanks in advance! 
Milind

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and asked Box directly.  This is the reply they sent me:

> You can only use the `mdfilters` parameter if you have a custom "template" in your enterprise account: https://box-content.readme.io/#metadata-object. The properties template doesn't work with the `mdfilters` parameter; however, properties DO get indexed in general searches.

If you have an Enterprise account with Box they can set up custom metadata templates that can be searched via the `mdfilters` parameter, otherwise use the `query` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Here's an [example](https://github.com/box/box-java-sdk/issues/285) provided, in Java, that comes straight from a member of the java-sdk [Box group on Github](https://github.com/box).

```
BoxSearch boxSearch = new BoxSearch(api);
BoxSearchParameters searchParams = new BoxSearchParameters();

BoxMetadataFilter metadataFilter = new BoxMetadataFilter();
metadataFilter.setScope("enterprise");
metadataFilter.setTemplateKey("myTemplate");
metadataFilter.addFilter("myField", "fieldValue");
searchParams.setMetadataFilter(metadataFilter);

PartialCollection<BoxItem.Info> searchResults = boxSearch.searchRange(0, 100, searchParams);
```

### WARNING

A file cannot be searched for based on its metadata for at least 5-10 minutes after updating the file with the metadata that you're using to search for the file. Refer to the accepted solution on this [forum question](https://community.box.com/t5/Platform-and-Development-Forum/Box-Search-Delay/td-p/40072), that was posted to the Box community and answered by a "trusted contributor", for an explanation as to why this behavior occurs.