# Search on global properties

Tags: box-api

Is it possible to do a search using the API on metadata in the properties template? I'm using the `mdfilters` parameter for the search request:

```
https://api.box.com/2.0/search?mdfilters=[{"templateKey":"properties", "scope":"global", "filters":{"docId": "1"}}]
```

The response I get is 404 Not Found:

```
{
  "message": "Instance not found for '\\\"view\\\", \\\"typeKeyKey\\\", \\\"properties\\\", \\\"searchFilterPanel\\\"'",
  "code": "tuple_not_found",
  "request_id": "870411128557159b487c8a"
}
```

I suspect that the properties template cannot be used in a metadata search, is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not with `mdfilters`. Use a regular search instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30903725/1081952) for more.